# FloatingPointError in QGIS

Tags: qgis, python

I'm trying to classify my study area by Semi-Automatic Classification Plugin

When I want to compare the spectral differences between two types of land-use, it shows that `FloatingPointError: invalid value encountered in greater_equal`

[image]

How could solve this error?

Comment: I have the same problem. Were you able to resolve this already?

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/ask). You can also [add a bounty](https://gis.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question once you have enough [reputation](https://gis.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation). - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/160078)

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

1. Close QGIS if open.
2. Delete folder ".qgis2" (usually in C:\Users...\user.qgis2).
3. Run QGIS again and reinstall plugin if uninstalled.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same error, I followed your instructions, but I didn't find the folder qgis2, would you please to clarify the second step,